# Is it possible to have client-side only validation on asp.net controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, validation

First, I know I can use Javascript, but let me explain.

My goal is to be able to use any of the validators:

- Required
- Regex
- Compare
- etc.

And benefit only from their client-side validation. I'm sub-classing inherited controls and preventing the name attribute from being rendered to the client. The reason is for sensitive data that I don't want going back to the server. Removing the name attribute prevents the value from being sent with the control.

Take required field for example, it always fails validation on the server because the value isn't sent. I could use a custom validator but want to leverage all the pre-built features of all the validate types.

Hoping someone had a creative idea, thought, or if I'm blind to the obvious, or if it's just straight up impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the `IsValid` property of the validator in the overridden `Validate` function of the page seems to work:

```
public override void Validate()
{
    base.Validate();
    rfvNotEmpty.IsValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Note: I don't know why my answer is the only one that has not been downvoted (yet) but I am not the guy who downvoted the other answers. :-)

Comment: lol. I hear ya. I'm looking at your answer now. Someone sank my battleship too and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you for un-sinking my battleship, if that was you. :)

Comment: Yes, it was me (upvoting to cancel somebody else's downvote). I think your idea is very good, but I haven't tried it to see if there are any down sides to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty only but if someone need it, I've got a simple solution.

You simply created your client-side validator to be Enabled="false" and in the PreRender event you enabled It, The server-side validation appear before the PreRender so it will be ignore because it's disabled, but the prerender will generate client-side code and the validator will be enabled and working.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit, it is an open source library for web development.

If you want to use standard Asp.Net Control, you can use the validation controller there is compare, custom, range, regex, and required field validator.

regards

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you question correctly you want your server side validation control to work client side , then you need to add reference of latest jquery file on your page as showing in example.

Server side control will validated client side and form will not be posted to server side until validated client side.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ValidationTest.aspx.vb" Inherits=".ValidationTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" CssClass="form-control"  />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            ID="rvtxtName"
            InitialValue=""
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtName"
            ForeColor="Red"
            ErrorMessage="*Field Required!"
            Display="Dynamic"
            ValidationGroup="add">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Save"  ValidationGroup="add" />
    </asp:Panel>


   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question.